# Azure Cosmos SQL - working with nested arrays and using LIKE keyword

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

For some time when I had to find particular element of array by particular value I've been using ARRAY_CONTAINS function. Now I have documents with nested arrays where I have to search not but particular value, but using regex.

As an example of document let me use one from official documentation:

```
{
  "id": "AndersenFamily",
  "lastName": "Andersen",
  "parents": [
     { "firstName": "Thomas" },
     { "firstName": "Mary Kay"}
  ],
  "children": [
     {
         "firstName": "Henriette Thaulow",
         "gender": "female",
         "grade": 5,
         "pets": [{ "givenName": "Fluffy" }]
     }
  ],
  "address": { "state": "WA", "county": "King", "city": "Seattle" },
  "creationDate": 1431620472,
  "isRegistered": true
}
```

What I need is to select and fully get all documents where at least one of `children` has at least one `pets` element where `givenName` contains "fluf".

What SQL query do I build to achieve it?

Comment: What have you tried so far that's not working?

Comment: I have no idea what to try :)
If I would need to filter by parents I would use:
SELECT * FROM d WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(d.parents, {"firstName": "myValue" }, true)
but in my case I need to:
1. Somehow apply "LIKE" keyword and use a regex expression, because I don't have particular value. And I don't know how to use LIKE inside of ARRAY_CONTAINS.
2. I have nested array so I can't use ARRAY_CONTAINS directly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that uses [JOINs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join) to flatten out the inner `pets` arrays and apply a filter, then return the entire matching family items:

```
SELECT VALUE f
FROM Families f
JOIN c IN f.children
JOIN p IN c.pets
WHERE p.givenName LIKE "%Fluf%"
```

The complexity of figuring out such queries is one reason why I think it's worth considering modeling data to be as flat as possible, including normalizing out to have separate `pets` items for example, which can be queried with direct property filters without dealing with nesting. Combining everything into a large `Family` object as the examples do isn't necessarily a good idea in practice depending on your goals.